# JTextPane fit to the underlaying JPanel and JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jtextpane

I have the following problem:
[image]

I have a `JTextPane` on the left filled with content and this `JTextPane` is placed into a `JScrollPane`. This `ScrollPane` is added to the `BorderLayout.CENTER` of a `JPanel` and this resulting `JPanel` is added to `BorderLayout.CENTER` of the underlaying `JFrame contentPane()`.

Now I want to spread this `JTextPane` all over the `JFrame/JPanel`. 
How can I achieve this?

Here is the code:

```
public class FinishPanelBuilder extends JPanel
{
  /**
   * Serial version UID.
   */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 4373044358025740572L;
  private Model model;

  /**
   * Constructor to call if you want to build up a new finish panel.
   * 
   * @param model
   */
  public FinishPanelBuilder()
  {
    buildFinishPanel();
  }

  /**
   * Builds up the panel.
   */
  public void buildFinishPanel()
  {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JTextWrapPane textPaneResult = new JTextWrapPane(); 
    //This is my own class of JTextPane to wrap text
    StyledDocument document = textPaneResult.getStyledDocument();

    textPaneResult.setEditable(false);
    textPaneResult.setBackground(Color.white);
    textPaneResult.setFont(panelLabel.getFont());
    textPaneResult.setAutoscrolls(true);
    textPaneResult.setLineWrap(false);

    JScrollPane scrollPaneTestResult = new JScrollPane(textPaneResult);
    scrollPaneTestResult.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8));

    panelLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8));
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
    add(panelLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    add(scrollPaneTestResult, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }
}
```

This complete code is called by a

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame(); 
frame.add(new FinishPanelBuilder();
```

Comment: Post some SSCCE which demonstrates how you positioned your components.

Comment: Everything works fine for me..Check your code again, maybe you put some panel on `EAST`.

Comment: Mhmmm...okay...I'll take a look again and post the answer if I find it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I did this again and it was okay. I don't know why. I think it is cause of a wrong method called `getScrollableTracksViewportWidth()` which was overrided.